# Retrieve data from mapbox geocoder

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

i only need the mapbox geocoding autocomplete without the map (to put the result with lat/lng in another request)

I managed to put it totally alone without the map using this :

```
<template>
    <div id='geocoder' class='geocoder'></div>
</template>

<script>
import MapboxGeocoder from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder'
require('../../node_modules/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/dist/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css')

mapboxgl.accessToken = '<your access token here>';
var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
    placeholder: 'Rechercher'
});
document.getElementById('geocoder').appendChild(geocoder.onAdd());
</script>
```

[image]

But now i would like to retrieve the data (specifically the lat/lng attribute in order to save it in my component and work with it)

How can i do that ? i've search through mapbox doc but did not found anything about that :/

Thanks in advance to the community

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the API docs https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/master/API.md#on you can use

```
geocoder.on('results', function(results) {
   console.log(results);
})
```

Comment: your answer look like it answer the question, so i will validate it :)
did not tested it though as i went with algolia.

Comment: That's fine, thanks. I wanted to answer anyway for anyone else landing here.

Comment: I find mapbox documentation not practical. After 15min diving into the docs, I found the solution here

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a cheaper and easier to integrate alternative :

https://community.algolia.com/places/documentation.html#using-npm

here is the simple code :

```
<template>
    <input type="search" id="address-input" placeholder="Where are we going?" />
</template>

<script>
import Places from 'places.js'

...
    mounted: function() {
        var placesAutocomplete = new Places({
            container: document.querySelector('#address-input')
        })
        placesAutocomplete.on('change', e => console.log(e.suggestion))
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by AndrewHarvey

You can get the results by subscribing to events.

```
var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
    placeholder: 'Rechercher'
});

geocoder.on("results", function(results){
    // You will get here all the results from your input query
}

geocoder.on("result", function(result) {
    // You will get the result of location that was selected from the drop-down.
}
```

Docs : https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/main/API.md#on