# Is mapbox geocoder API available for usage without a map?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am reading through [mapbox JS api](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) but don't seem to find any the geocoding API call that would enable me to provide place lookup using my own typeahead component. So basically I am after sending out a query and receiving an array of results.

I **do not** mean the example on [how to place geocoder Control on or off the map](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder-outside-the-map/), but rather how can I provide places lookup in my own form [Angular, React, whatever] that does not display any map. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATE May 2020]

[Mapbox now does allow you to use a Geocoder without using a map](https://www.mapbox.com/legal/tos#%5BGAGA%5D) (search form with autocomplete)

> July 1, 2019: Removed the default restriction that Services have to be
>   used in conjunction with a Mapbox map. **Point of interest results from
>   the Geocoding API and Enterprise Boundaries must still be used in
>   conjunction with a Mapbox map**.

Examples can be found [from the Mapbox website](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder-no-map/) and [from Mapbox Github page](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder).

This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51407782) shows an alternative plugin/ service called [Algolia](https://community.algolia.com/places/documentation.html#using-npm) that you can use to create a Geocoder.

Another alternative is to use [Geocodio](https://www.geocod.io/geocodio-vs-mapbox-geocoding-comparison/).

However, both Geocodio AND Mapbox Geocoder (*without a map present*) **do not** support POI (Point of Interest) 
E.g. A named place including commercial businesses, public buildings, monuments, and parks, etc.

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently the violation of [Mapbox's terms of service](https://www.mapbox.com/tos/#geocoding):

> You may only use responses from the Geocoding API ("Geocodes") in
>   conjunction with a Mapbox map.

That's the reason why [`mapbox-gl-js`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js) `MapboxGeocoder` control (which consumes [Mapbox Geocoding API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#geocoding)) comes in conjunction with a Mapbox map only and means your scenario is **not** supported.

Comment: If you have the Enterprise Geocoding plan https://www.mapbox.com/search/ then you can use the Geocoding API without a map

Answer (score 0):

July 1, 2019: Removed the default restriction that Services have to be used in conjunction with a Mapbox map. Point of interest results from the Geocoding API and Enterprise Boundaries must still be used in conjunction with a Mapbox map.

Comment: In the Service Terms I can't see where it says that it must be used with a Mapbox map. https://www.mapbox.com/legal/service-terms